# Total Duration (no double counting) - Python - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame as shown below. The columns are date, color, time, and duration (in seconds). I need to calculate the amount of time throughout a day that we are displaying a color.

```
date          color          start time            duration(seconds)
2021-07-06    RED            11:00:00.00           5
2021-07-06    RED            11:00:00.00           9
2021-07-06    BLUE           11:00:00.00           3
2021-07-06    RED            11:00:00.00           3
2021-07-06    BLUE           12:00:00.00           10
2021-07-06    BLUE           12:00:00.00           7
2021-07-06    RED            12:00:00.00           9
2021-07-06    BLUE           12:00:00.00           5
2021-07-06    RED            12:00:00.00           1
2021-07-06    RED            12:00:00.00           2
```

For example, in a 24 hour day I need to understand how long we are displaying a color. There will be a variable number of colors each day, staggered start times, and varying durations.

If we're looking at the color red in the example above, the duration of displaying red would be **18 seconds**. We don't double count any display overlaps.

My desired output would be a DataFrame which tells me how long each color was displayed for, and how long all colors were displayed. The maximum amount of time for each color, or any color can only be 24 hours. For the example above, the answer would be:

Red Duration: 18 seconds
Blue Duration: 13 seconds
Total Duration: 19 seconds

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: So, it looks like you want the sum of the max of each color's duration grouped by date and start time?

Comment: Is there ever any case where the duration is longer than an hour for any given start time? Are your start times always binned by the hour?

Comment: There's no limit to the duration. The start times are not binned by the hour, they can be anything, such as 11:59:59.9999.

Comment: Then you should have included that information in your post, and provided more representative sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each row in your data corresponds to an interval.  For any colour, how many intervals overlap a point in time is a step function.  A package called staircase has been built upon pandas and numpy for analysis with step functions.

**setup**

I'm going to use different data, to highlight that this approach works with staggered start times (which your example doesn't have).  I'm also combining date and start time to simplify

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "color":["RED", "RED","BLUE","RED","BLUE","BLUE","RED","BLUE","RED","RED"],
        "start":[
            pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:00"),
            pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:02"),
            pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:01"),
            pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:04"),
            pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:05"),
            pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:05"),
            pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:08"),
            pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:07"),
            pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:12"),
            pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:14"),
        ],
        "duration":[5,4,7,3,4,6,4,7,2,3]
    }
)

df["end"] = df["start"] + pd.to_timedelta(df["duration"], "s")
```

**solution**

We'll create a step function for each colour. A step function is represented by the `staircase.Stairs clas`s. This class is to staircase as Series is to pandas. To do this we group the dataframe on this variable and pass the sub-dataframes to the [Stairs constructor](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/reference/api/staircase.Stairs.__init__.html#staircase.Stairs.__init__).

```
import staircase as sc

stepfunctions = df.groupby("color").apply(sc.Stairs, "start", "end")
```

Our `stepfunctions` variable looks like this. It is a series, with a multi-index, and values are `Stairs` objects.

```
color
BLUE    <staircase.Stairs, id=2640555912520>
RED     <staircase.Stairs, id=2640555814408>
dtype: object
```

We can add these step functions together to create one for the total

```
stepfunctions["TOTAL"] = stepfunctions.sum()
```

There are many things you can do with step functions in staircase including plotting.

```
stepfunctions["RED"].plot(style="hlines")
```

[image: step function for RED]

Since you do not want to count overlaps, we need to convert each step function to a boolean valued one - i.e. if it is non zero set it to 1.

```
stepfunctions = stepfunctions.apply(sc.Stairs.make_boolean)
```

Now plotting the step function for RED again gives us

[image]

What you are wanting to do is [create bins and integrate](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/reference/api/staircase.StairsSlicer.integral.html#staircase.StairsSlicer.integral) (find the area under) these step functions. For a step function sf this means the following calculation. Let's say your bins are 5 second bins, (as opposed to daily), just to make it interesting

```
bins = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:00"), freq = "5s", periods=4) 

bin_sums = stepfunctions.apply(lambda sf: sf.slice(bins).integral())
```

This gives you a dataframe, indexed by color, with columns for each bin.  We'll melt it to display it better

```
bin_sums.melt(var_name="bin", ignore_index=False)

color                                         bin           value                                                           
BLUE   [2021-07-06 11:00:00, 2021-07-06 11:00:05) 0 days 00:00:04
RED    [2021-07-06 11:00:00, 2021-07-06 11:00:05) 0 days 00:00:05
TOTAL  [2021-07-06 11:00:00, 2021-07-06 11:00:05) 0 days 00:00:05
BLUE   [2021-07-06 11:00:05, 2021-07-06 11:00:10) 0 days 00:00:05
RED    [2021-07-06 11:00:05, 2021-07-06 11:00:10) 0 days 00:00:04
TOTAL  [2021-07-06 11:00:05, 2021-07-06 11:00:10) 0 days 00:00:05
BLUE   [2021-07-06 11:00:10, 2021-07-06 11:00:15) 0 days 00:00:04
RED    [2021-07-06 11:00:10, 2021-07-06 11:00:15) 0 days 00:00:05
TOTAL  [2021-07-06 11:00:10, 2021-07-06 11:00:15) 0 days 00:00:05
```

So this approach

- handles overlaps
- handles intervals crossing bin boundaries

**note**:
I am the creator of staircase.  Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: This seems like what I am trying to do. I'm going to test it now and see how it results for me. At this point, I am not creating bins, so all I need is in a given day the duration each color is displayed and the duration any color is displayed. I'm going to branch off where you convert each step function to a boolean value and see if it results in the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Cool, in that case you can remove the `slice` and just use `stepfunctions.apply(sc.Stairs.integral)`

Comment: Did you import a specific plotting library? When I try to recreate your steps I get the following error at the `stepfunctions["RED"].plot(style="hlines")` step: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: Nah it just runs of matplotlib. What version of staircase, and pandas do you have?

Comment: Pandas has a couple of open issues around inconsistent behaviour with `pandas.DataFrame.query` which is being called when `style=hlines`. It seems to boil down to whether `numexpr` is installed or not. If you call the plot function without any args it may be a workaround in the meantime (or uninstall `numexpr`).

Comment: @left-them-on-red staircase v2.1.1 has a bugfix for this issue and is now on pypi for pip install.

Comment: Thank you - I'll update it now staircase now!

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, similar to the one with `staircase` which involves interval arrays instead of step functions.  It uses a package [`piso`](https://piso.readthedocs.io) which is built for set operations with pandas interval classes

**setup**

Assume the same setup as `staircase` solution

**solution**

For each colour create `pandas.arrays.IntervalArrays` (or `pandas.IntervalIndex`)

```
import piso

interval_arrays = df.groupby("color").apply(lambda d: pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays(d["start"], d["end"]))
```

`interval_arrays` looks like this

```
color
BLUE     [(2021-07-06 11:00:01, 2021-07-06 11:00:08], (...
RED      [(2021-07-06 11:00:00, 2021-07-06 11:00:05], (...
dtype: object
```

We need to create the union of these intervals in each array

```
interval_arrays = interval_arrays.apply(piso.union)
```

We then create the union of these two arrays to get the total

```
interval_arrays["TOTAL"] = piso.union(*interval_arrays)
```

`interval_arrays` looks like this

```
color
BLUE     [(2021-07-06 11:00:01, 2021-07-06 11:00:08], (...
RED      [(2021-07-06 11:00:00, 2021-07-06 11:00:05], (...
TOTAL         [(2021-07-06 11:00:00, 2021-07-06 11:00:17]]
dtype: object
```

create bins as a `pandas.IntervalIndex`

```
bins = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp("2021-07-06 11:00:00"), freq = "5s", periods=4)
ii_bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(bins)
```

Then use [piso.coverage()](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/piso.coverage.html#piso.coverage) which takes an interval array, and a domain, and returns the fraction of the domain (i.e. bin) covered by the intervals in the array.  If we multiply the fraction by the bin size then it will be the total time

```
interval_arrays.apply(lambda ia: pd.Series([piso.coverage(ia, bin)*bin.length for bin in ii_bins]))
```

This results in a dataframe

```
color               0               1               2                                                
BLUE  0 days 00:00:04 0 days 00:00:05 0 days 00:00:04
RED   0 days 00:00:05 0 days 00:00:04 0 days 00:00:05
TOTAL 0 days 00:00:05 0 days 00:00:05 0 days 00:00:05
```

columns are bin indices.  You can switch them out for the intervals `ii_bins` if you want to, and perhaps melt the dataframe to get tidy data.

This approach also handles overlaps and handles intervals crossing bin boundaries.